# How to implemet a reCaptcha on react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm working on implementing a reCaptcha validator for a login screen on a react-native app which has to work both on web and mobile environments.

As I'm fairly new as a programmer and have little experience on react-native I'm aware that I may have missed something very basic/obvious which is why I've decided to ask this, even though this question has already been asked a couple of times before.

I'm trying [this](https://github.com/douglasjunior/react-native-recaptcha-that-works) library since it is the most popular one on NPMjs.

On the login screen page I'm calling the component
`<RecaptchaComponent/>` and this is the code I have so far within the component.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Recaptcha, { RecaptchaHandles } from "react-native-recaptcha-that-works";

export const Recaptcha_Component = () => {

    let url = "mySiteUrl";
    let key = "publicKey";

    const recaptcha: any = useRef<RecaptchaHandles>();

    const send = () => {
        console.log('send!');
        recaptcha.current?.open();
    };

    const onVerify = (token: string) => {
        console.log('success!', token);
    };

    const onExpire = () => {
        console.warn('expired!');
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Recaptcha
                ref={recaptcha}
                siteKey={key}
                baseUrl={url}
                onVerify={onVerify}
                onExpire={onExpire}
                size={"invisible"}
            />
            <Button title="Send" onPress={send} />
        </View >
    )
}
```

When I press the Send button in the app I see an small loading indicator but nothing happens after that. On the console I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe3i8.png) warning message.

Answer (score 2):

first create recaptcha keys at
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

then you create an new component like this:

```
const GetRecaptcha = (props) => {
const onMessage = (data) => {

    console.log('recaptcha', data.nativeEvent.data)
    //here you can put your action to perform(check validation on your server or somthing)
    props.action(data.nativeEvent.data);

};

return <View style={{}}>

    <WebView
        style={{height: 0}}
        onMessage={async (e) => await onMessage(e)}
        containerStyle={{height: 0}}
        source={{
            html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=RECAPTCHA-KEY"></script>
        <script>
        function onLoad(e) {
         
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('RECAPTCHA-KEY', {action: 'submit'}).then((token) => {
                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(token);
                });
            }) 
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="onLoad()">
        </body>
        </html>`
        , baseUrl: 'your-url',
    }}/>


</View>;
};
```

you could use this component from other component as this example:

```
const action=(token)=>{
   // validate key on server
   if(token){
    //do some action
   }else{
   //do some action
   }
  }
  const App=()=>{
  return <GetRecaptcha action={action}/>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but in order to work with that ref you need to initialize it as null:

`const recaptcha: any = useRef<RecaptchaHandles>(null);`

Also, get rid of the 'any' - you already declared it as an instance of RecaptchaHandles.
And last, use google dev site key and url if you are in dev mode.
On production use your own key and url

Google dev site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
Google base url: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api